# Parsing XML using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Can I get some help parsing the "my_cool_id" from the following xml using XDocument?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
  <fields>
    <field name="field_name_1">
      <value>12345</value>
    </field>
    <field name="my_cool_id">
      <value>12345</value>
    </field>
    <field name="field_name_2">
      <value>12345</value>
    </field>
    <field name="field_name_3">
      <value>12345</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</xfdf>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  what was the expected result of your tries? what didn't work as expected? When you want to parse it what do you wish the result to be?

Comment: Xpath: `//field[@name='my_cool_id']/value/text()`

Comment: @MarcB: I don't think that will work as-is, due to namespaces.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I suspect you're being stumped by the namespace. Try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/";

foreach (XElement element in doc.Root
                                .Element(ns + "fields")
                                .Elements(ns + "field"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Value: {1}",
                      (string) element.Attribute("name"),
                      (string) element.Element(ns + "value"));
}
```

Or to find just the one specific element:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/";
var field = doc.Descendants(ns + "field")
               .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "my_cool_id")
               .FirstOrDefault();

if (field != null)
{
    string value = (string) field.Element("value");
    // Use value here
}
```