# How do I parse text from complex type xml in c# using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta>
    <field type="xs-string" name="AssetId">TF00000002</field>
    <field type="xs-string" name="Title">TitleOfAsset</field>
</meta>
```

I have this XML loaded in to a XDocument using the function

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData)
```

However, I want to be able to retrieve the text fields "TF00000002" and "TitleOfAsset" ... How do I go about doing this?

```
templateMetaData.assetID = doc
    .Descendants()
    .Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "AssetId")
    .ToString();
```

returns:

```
 System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
```

Can anyone shine a light on this?

Comment: `Doesn't work.` is not very precise... can you describe what exactly happens?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is far too vague a description. What happened? (Hint: `Where` returns a sequence, not a single value, and you're currently looking at the element name, not the `name` attribute).

Comment: Sorry, yes. It returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]" instead of the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML using XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798852/parsing-xml-using-xdocument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are calling `ToString` on an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which will never give you the expected result, instead look for `field` elements under your `Root` and get their value:

```
var values = doc.Root
           .Elements("field")
           .Select(element => (string)element);
```

If you want to access your values using the `name` attribute you can use `Dictionary`:

```
var values = doc.Root
           .Elements("field")
           .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), x => (string)x);
```

Then you can access the value of `AssetId`:

```
var id = values["AssetId"];
```

Comment: I think `element => element.Value` would make more sense. Just a suggestion.

Comment: This code just tells me that the sequence contains no elements whenever I change "field" to "AssetId" edit: just saw your edit... trying that now

Comment: @user3780459 because AssetId is the value of your name attribute. it is **not** an XElement

Comment: OK so now I have this code instead

                var assetID = doc.Root.Elements("xs-string").ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("AssetId"), x => (string)x);

and it also doesn't return the value of the AssetId. Am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: are you kidding with me ? why did you write .Elements("xs-string") ? do you see anything like that in my answer ?

Comment: sorry... I didn't read you correctly. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your first example will also select the TEXT() of any children elements. The OP's sample doesn't have any, but other's might.