# I created a config xml file. But I cant read the file aftr <CMX_FPT> .in my Windows form.I am using c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReadXMLConfig>
<CmdVar>MyCmdVar</CmdVar>
<CmdRetVar>MyCmdRetVar</CmdRetVar>
<PathExpression><![CDATA[C:\Temp[OPC:MyVar].xml]]></PathExpression>

    <!--TODO Description-->
<CMX_FPT>
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\ILN" Variable="FlxILN" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\FirmenName" Variable="FlxFirmenName" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\KundenName" Variable="FlxKundenName" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\EtikettProdukt" Variable="FlxEtikettProdukt" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\EtikettPalette" Variable="FlxEtikettPalette" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\KundenILN" Variable="FlxKundenILN" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\AuftragNummer" Variable="FlxAuftragNummer" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\Kontrakt" Variable="FlxKontrakt" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\AbrufNummer" Variable="FlxAbrufNummer" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\ZusatzText" Variable="FlxZusatzText" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\AuftragsnrBuchung" Variable="FlxAuftragsnrBuchung" />
<Item XPATH="CMX_FPT\\AuftragsPos" Variable="FlxAuftragPos" />

</CMX_FPT>
</ReadXMLConfig>
```

I want to read this XML file, but I can't read the file after the first four lines.
My code so far:

```
string myFile = userSelectedFilePath;
dataSet1.ReadXml(myFile);

DataSet myDAta = FlipDataSet(dataSet1);
DataView my_DataView = myDAta.Tables[0].DefaultView;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = my_DataView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking at the first `Table` (`Tables[0]`). The rest of them are in the other items in that DataTableCollection.

Comment: tables[1] shows me cmx_fpt  ..but nothin else n if i go to [2] ..it shows n error

Comment: Hmm...Tried loading your XML into a dataset and I can see the Items with the XPATH attributes on Tables[2]. Maybe add an XmlReadMode parameter (e.g. `dataSet1.ReadXml(myFile,XmlReadMode.InferSchema);`)

Comment: I am now trying to read the file using xmlreader or xdocument..can u give me some assistance how i can do that for this file...

Comment: I think that's a good decision. Check thse links out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798852/parsing-xml-using-xdocument (XDocument) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(VS.95).aspx (XmlReader)