# Convert List to array and store it onto file system

Tags: c#, arrays, save, filesystems

I have a list which is of type `ListItem`

The `ListItem` is a custom class I made and it looks like following:

```
public class ItemList
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
    public string GalleryURL { get; set; }
}
```

I need to store this List into a folder on my project which looks like this:

```
/Helpers/CachedResults/FileGoesHere
```

And so that I can reconstruct that list each time whenever I need it back in code...

Comment: Perhaps XML serialization? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml

Comment: This could be it, could you show me a practical example with my case ? :)

Comment: Guys I don't want to serialize it to XML... the code before the list is built I actually converted the XML file into this list.. Now I need to just store it into some kind of file so that I can rebuild it when needed...

Comment: Maybe bytes array or something like that?? Something simple and easy so that I can rebuild that file back to this original list :D

Comment: Well, you can serialize your list to xml and unserialize it back to your list.

Comment: @Kinetic Yeah I can see that from the link... But once I serialize it to XML, how do I store it and read from that Serialized XML file to rebuild it? I haven't seen that on the link u supplied

Comment: deserialise back to xml, you should make your question clear?

Comment: read that file using code

Comment: How to unserialize object from XML : stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/… – Kinetic 11 secs ago    edit

Comment: @viveknuna can u show me an example what you mean by that ? :)

Comment: @Kinetic that's a lot of code... there has to be a simpler way than that :/

Comment: A lot of code?  Are you kidding me?

Comment: u should follow the link provided by @Kinetic

Comment: You need about three lines of code for serialization and about the same for unserialization.

Comment: @Kinetic it's way more than just 3 lines... It is 3 lines when you setup and map all the classes... The XML response that I get from ebay is ugly and I should re-do every bit piece of code that I did to reconstruct the XML to do this.. It's just not the way to go with this one...

Comment: I fail to see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with LINQ to XML.

To use it, you need to add a reference to System.Xml.Linq (in VS, right-click References -> Add Reference -> check System.Xml.Linq).

You don't need to convert the List into an array, but of course, you can, if you want. That's done simply with the `list.ToArray()` method.

The writing-to-file code would be:

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();

// (the list is populated)

XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(); // create empty document
XElement root = new XElement("list"); // add root element, XML requires one single root element
xDocument.Add(root); // add root to document
foreach(var listItem in list) 
{
    var xElement = new XElement("list-item", // <list-item />
        new XAttribute("id", listItem.ItemID), // id="id"
        new XAttribute("quantity-sold", listItem.QuantitySold), // quantity-sold=5
        new XAttribute("gallery-url", listItem.GalleryURL) // gallery-url="foo/bar"
    );
    root.Add(xElement); // add list-item element to root
}

xDocument.Save("Helpers/CachedResults/File.xml"); // save file
```

**Note that the directory must exist for `Save` to work!**

Then parsing:

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("Helpers/CachedResults/File.xml"); // load from file
XElement root = xDocument.Element("list"); // get root element

foreach (XElement xElement in root.Elements("list-item")) // traverse through elements inside root element
{
    list.Add(new ListItem // add list items
    {
        ItemID = xElement.Attribute("id").Value, // parse id
        QuantitySold = Int32.Parse(xElement.Attribute("quantity-sold").Value), // parse int for QuantitySold
        GalleryURL = xElement.Attribute("gallery-url").Value // parse url
    });
}
```

And we're done!

Comment: It's basically manual XML serialization and unserialization.  You'll get the same result.  A perfectly good answer.

Comment: Well you did write the code nicely, I gotta tell you that... But this isn't the way to go since I actually just before thist List<ListItem> is created, I did exactly parse the XML document that I got from ebay and converted it to this list of items :D... This would be a step-back or redoing everything I actually did XD

Comment: Why would you need to redo your "ebay code" though?

Comment: Here's the thing, I get the response from ebay for specific items (ID's) that I pass through the XML request to ebay... ebay returns me the results in the form of XML file. I convert the XML responses I got from ebay into this List<ReusltItem> and now I'm trying to save that list onto the file system so that I can re-use it to display the result to the end user (sorta way of caching the results)...

Comment: Sounds ok to me, but I still fail to see what you would need to recode in this process.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> Now I need to just store it into some kind of file so that I can
>   rebuild it when needed...

you just need the following lines:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, xml);
xml = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

where `xml` is the string you get from serializing / the serialized string that you stored previously and want to deserialize)

(This is besides the actual serialization that I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708658/convert-list-to-array-and-store-it-onto-file-system/40709261#comment68645773_40708658): [Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml))

**EDIT**

From the comments, it seems like your trying to parse xml that you receive. Then perhaps you should consider using the classes that were made for that. See [Parsing XML using XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798852/parsing-xml-using-xdocument) .

Comment: what is "xml" in this answer?

Comment: It could be the list of responses that I received from eBay... Hold on I'll try this... It might be the solution

Comment: @ispiro is there any way to read it line by line ?? Since every line I'll write in is basically an XML document for itself lol..

Comment: @User987 Is `File.ReadAllLines` better?

Comment: @Kinetic updated the answer with that.

Comment: mm I tried ReadAllLines but for some reason when I combine it with elementat method I get a following result: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>

I should get the XML from line 1 in the file, but instead I get only this above ?

Comment: @User987 That's the standard first line of an XML file.

Comment: @User987 See my edit to my answer.