# Load XML File and turn into strings

Tags: c#, xml

I have some trouble loading an XML File and turn it into string (like `<XBoxIP></XBoxIP>` and I want whats in between them); this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1-0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<Config>
    <XBoxIP></XBoxIP>
    <XBoxPort></XBoxPort>
    <XBoxUser></XBoxUser>
    <XBoxPassword></XBoxPassword>
    <XBoxSongPath></XBoxSongPath>
    <LocalSongPath></LocalSongPath>
</Config>
```

Or is my XML File maybe incorrect?
Thanks for the help, i am new to C# and XML.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path + "/Config.xml");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
```

is the code im currently using, and i don't really know what to do after that.

Comment: Please show the problematic code also

Comment: @RufusL `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(path + "/Config.xml");
                string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;` and i don't know what to do after that :/

Comment: Is your object serializable?

Comment: @random No, i don't think so.

Comment: Ah, ok. It sounds more like you're looking for a tutorial on how to read an xml file in c#.

Comment: @RufusL Editited.

Comment: Yeah im probably looking for that! @RufusL but i don't find examples that fit my xml file.

Comment: The code you posted works for me. Only thing you need to change is version to `1.0` and encoding to `UTF-8`

Comment: Maybe you want [Parsing XML using XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798852/parsing-xml-using-xdocument).  You should prefer using `XDocument` to the older `XmlDocument`, see [XDocument or XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1542073/3744182).

Comment: There is no values in the xml so you should be getting nothing back.

Comment: On closer inspection, your XML is not valid or well-formed.  Upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error *XML version "1-0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported.*  `"1.0"` and `"1.1"` are both [recognized XML versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Versions) but `"1-0"` is not.  See also https://dotnetfiddle.net/VK1aY0 that shows the same error with .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make slight change to your xml and i hope it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> //make changes here
<Config>
    <XBoxIP></XBoxIP>
    <XBoxPort></XBoxPort>
    <XBoxUser></XBoxUser>
    <XBoxPassword></XBoxPassword>
    <XBoxSongPath></XBoxSongPath>
    <LocalSongPath></LocalSongPath>
</Config>
```

you can also used below property. The OuterXml property returns a string version of the xml.

```
xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```